# R - plot reactive subset with plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, subset, reactive

I want to make a plot based on a reactive subset, it works to display my table but i am not able to take the columns of the subset in order to plot that.

```
structure(list(WEG = c(0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04), VERTIKAL_KRAFT_FY = c(358.77, 
358.78, 358.78, 358.79, 358.79, 358.8), VERSCHIEBEKRAFT_FX = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), HD = c(-9.39, -9.39, -9.41, -9.36, -9.36, -9.38
), PROBE_NR = c(6812L, 6812L, 6812L, 6812L, 6812L, 6812L), ZYKLUS = c(101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")




ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Select1","Select Test",unique(d$PROBE_NR)),
  selectInput("Select2","Select Cycle",choices = NULL)

  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("view"),
    plotlyOutput('plot'),
  )
  
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  
  observeEvent(input$Select1,{
    updateSelectInput(session,'Select2',
                      choices=unique(d$ZYKLUS[d$PROBE_NR==input$Select1]))
  })
  
  newData <- reactive({
    t <- subset(d, d$PROBE_NR == input$Select1 & d$ZYKLUS %in% input$Select2) #subset
    return(t)
  })
  
  output$view <- renderTable({ newData() }) 
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    data = newData()
    plot<-plot_ly(data, color = ~source, x = ~WEG, y = ~HD, mode = "lines", type = "scatter") %>% 
      layout( xaxis = list( title=input$Selectx), 
              yaxis = list( title=input$Selecty ), title = "Plot1" )
    plot
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like to take some columns of the subset t in order to plot them.

[image: This is my Data Frame, i do select a PROBE and a ZYKLUS an create the subset "t", from this subset i would like to create a line plot with the column WEG as xaxis and HD as Yaxis]

Comment: Please provide a **reproducible** example.

Comment: @ismirsehregal just updated the description

Comment: Please use dput to provide examples.

Comment: @Florian uodated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `source` specified as plotly's `color` argument doesn't exist in your `data.frame`. Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

d <- structure(
  list(
    WEG = c(0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04),
    VERTIKAL_KRAFT_FY = c(358.77,
                          358.78, 358.78, 358.79, 358.79, 358.8),
    VERSCHIEBEKRAFT_FX = c(0,
                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    HD = c(-9.39, -9.39, -9.41, -9.36, -9.36, -9.38),
    PROBE_NR = c(6812L, 6812L, 6812L, 6812L, 6812L, 6812L),
    ZYKLUS = c(101L,
               101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 6L),
  class = "data.frame"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Select1", "Select Test", unique(d$PROBE_NR)),
  selectInput("Select2", "Select Cycle", choices = NULL),
  mainPanel(tableOutput("view"),
            plotlyOutput("plot"))
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$Select1, {
    updateSelectInput(session, 'Select2',
                      choices = unique(d$ZYKLUS[d$PROBE_NR == input$Select1]))
  })
  
  newData <- reactive({
    subset(d, d$PROBE_NR == input$Select1 & d$ZYKLUS %in% input$Select2)
  })
  
  output$view <- renderTable({
    newData()
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      data = newData(),
      # color = ~ source,
      x = ~ WEG,
      y = ~ HD,
      mode = "lines",
      type = "scatter"
    ) %>%
      layout(
        xaxis = list(title = input$Selectx),
        yaxis = list(title = input$Selecty),
        title = "Plot1"
      )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: result]